# <a> with same size of it's <li> parent with display: table-cell

Tags: html, css

I have a list with `a` some with one line, others with two lines. How I can force to have the same height and width as his `li` parent with `display:table-cell` and vertically align text?

```css
ul {
  display:table;
  width:700px;
}

li {
  display:table-cell;
  border-right:3px solid white;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align:center;
  background-color:#ddd;
}

a {
  display:block;
  height:100%;      
  background-color:#aaa;
  padding:1em 1.2em;  
}

a:hover {
  background-color:red
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="">Example 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Example 2 two lines</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Example 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Example 4 two lines</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Example 5</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Example 6</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Example 7</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Not sure how to solve it inside table display, but you could use flex, e.g: https://jsfiddle.net/svr11hjf/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`height:100%` will only work if all of the parents have a height set and one of them is not a percentage (unless all heights up to the body and html tags have percentage heights)

With this in mind, we can set `height:100%` on the `li` and then give the `ul` a height of 0 - as you have used `display:table`, tables will always grow to the height of their content

```css
ul {
  display:table;
  width:700px;
  height:0;       /* add this */
  table-layout:fixed;
}

li {
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
  text-align:center;
  border-right:3px solid white;
  background-color:#ddd;
  height:100%;       /* add this */
}

a {
  display:block;
  height: 100%;      
  background-color:#aaa;
  padding:1em 1.2em;  
  box-sizing: border-box; /* add this to get rid of the big gap at the bottom */
}

a:hover {
  background-color:red
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="">Example 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Example 2 two lines</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Example 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Example 4 two lines</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Example 5</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Example 6</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Example 7</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Update**

Ok if you are only using tables for vertical alignment, then I would change this to flex - it gives you more control over child elements:

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  width: 700px;
}
li {
  display: flex;
  margin-right: 3px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
}
a {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: #aaa;
  padding: 1em 1.2em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
a:hover {
  background-color: red
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="">Example 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Example 2 two lines</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Example 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Example 4 two lines</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Example 5</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Example 6</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Example 7</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The vertical align is not correct with this example.

Comment: You have not mentioned anything about vertical align in your question.  Please state how you want it so I can edit my answer to match

Comment: Perfect solution!

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the padding and background color to the parent `<li>` elements, like this:

```css
ul {
  display:table;
  width:500px;
}

li {
  display:table-cell;
  border-right:3px solid white;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align:center;
  padding:1em 1.2em; 
  background-color:#aaa;
}

a {
  display:table-cell;
  height:100%; 
  vertical-align:middle;
}

a:hover {
  background-color:red
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="">Example 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Example 2 two lines</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Example 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Example 4 two lines</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Example 5</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Example 6</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Example 7</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Then vertical align is not perfect

Comment: OK - updated the answer to make the `<a>` elements `display:table-cell`, and `vertical-align:middle`.  Is that the alignment you're after?

Comment: Usually, you would want to be able to click the whole `li` element here. But now, only the text part is clickable.

Comment: I need the entire block is clickable

Answer (score 0):

A very quick solution is to change the `display`setting on the `ul` to `flex`:

```css
ul {
  display:flex;
  width:700px;
}

li {
  display:table-cell;
  border-right:3px solid white;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align:center;
  background-color:#ddd;
}

a {
  display:block;
  height:100%;      
  background-color:#aaa;
  padding:1em 1.2em 0 1.2em;  
}

a:hover {
  background-color:red
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="">Example 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Example 2 two lines</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Example 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Example 4 two lines</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Example 5</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Example 6</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Example 7</a></li>
</ul>
```

(I also changed to bottom padding for `a` which was too much)

Answer (score -3):

First, you cannot set same height to those `li` > `a` without setting their CSS to `white-space: nowrap;` unless you put some fixed `height:200px;` in the CSS (not recommended)

You can try this.

```
li {
    display: table-cell;
    border-right: 3px solid white;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: center;
    background-color: #ddd;
    width: 10%;
}
a {
    display: block;
    background-color: #aaa;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

10% width is added in the `li` element to dynamically adjust the width depending on the parent size `ul`.

Comment: Setting `white-space: nowrap` contradicts OP’s desire to actually wrap those buttons…